# How to change Google from speak now Voice Search dialogue box in any app?

Tags: android, google-voice-search

I have searched a lot but nothing lead me towards this what i am trying to do, so i am here to take expert's opinion, is it possible to change the google text or icon shown in screenshot i have attached in question, somehow i kind of know this that it is nearly impossible but there is a load of geniuses in world who can make anything possible so guide me how can i do it in any app?

[image]

Comment: why do you want to change this?

Comment: just because of learning purpose, and curiosity if there is any possibility to change it.